# Integer solutions of $2\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}n\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{q\pi}n\right)+4\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}n\right)\cos\left(\frac{q\pi}n\right)=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, trigonometric-sums, trigonometric-functions

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4760492/1096489) on MSE yesterday. Due to observations that I have made only after that, I feel that it may be a much harder problem than it looks like. So, I am posting the question here as well.

I came across the following problem while trying to solve an eigenvalue problem in my physics research. I want to know the integer solutions of the following equation

> $$ \cos\left(\frac{p\pi}n\right) + \cos\left(\frac{q\pi}n\right) + 2 \cos\left(\frac{p\pi}n\right) \cos\left(\frac{q\pi}n\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$
> where $p, q \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$.

I have already observed that if $n = 6k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then there is an immediate solution $p = 2k, q = 3k$. From numerical considerations, it seems that there are no solutions when $6 \not\mid n$. But, I do not have any explanation for it. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Now that I have an answer to it, I will keep this question open for two more days to see if any other answers come in that use more elementary methods, and then accept the answer.

Comment: Posted also on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4760492/11619). Please don't do that. Like never. Most likely you didn't think about it, but what may happen is that people waste time rediscovering ideas posted elsewhere. Some may find it a bit impolite. It is a strong recommendation that you either post on one site only, or otherwise crosslink the two versions so that all and sundry are aware of each others ideas.

Comment: Two references that may be relevant. Conway and Jones, Trigonometric diophantine equations, Acta Arithmetica XXX (1976) 229-240 (Theorem 6 gives all vanishing sums of nine or fewer roots of unity), http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa30/aa3033.pdf and my paper, Myerson, G. Rational products of sines of rational angles. Aequat. Math. 45, 70–82 (1993). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01844426

Comment: @Gerry, your comment would make a fine answer to [this old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/902901/11619) also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am extremely sorry, I didn't know this, I am new to this place. I will never repeat this again. I will edit both my questions immediately.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. It was clear (at least to me) that you were simply unaware of this norm.

Comment: If you do cross-post in future, please wait a suitable time (no less than a week!) to allow M.SE users a chance to have a go at the problem first.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, these are the only solutions. Let $\alpha = e^{p \pi i/n}$ and $\beta = e^{q \pi i/n}$. So the equation is
$$4 \left( \frac{\alpha+\alpha^{-1}}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{\beta+\beta^{-1}}{2} \right) + 2  \left( \frac{\alpha+\alpha^{-1}}{2} \right) + 2  \left( \frac{\beta+\beta^{-1}}{2} \right) =1.$$

We rewrite this as
$$\alpha \beta + \alpha + \alpha \beta^{-1} + \beta + \beta^{-1} + \alpha^{-1} \beta + \alpha^{-1} + \alpha^{-1} \beta^{-1} = 1.$$
$$\alpha \beta + \alpha + \alpha \beta^{-1} + \beta + 1+\beta^{-1} + \alpha^{-1} \beta + \alpha^{-1} + \alpha^{-1} \beta^{-1} = 2.$$
$$(\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}) (\beta + 1 + \beta^{-1}) = 2. \quad \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}$$
So we want to solve equation \eqref{1} in roots of unity. The conjecture in the question, which we will prove, is that the only solutions are $(\alpha, \beta) = (e^{\pm i \pi/3}, e^{\pm i \pi/4})$ or $(e^{\pm i \pi/4}, e^{\pm i \pi/3})$, so $(\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}, \beta + 1 + \beta^{-1}) = (2,1)$ or $(1,2)$.

This solution uses the language of algebraic number theory, which I'm afraid may not be familiar to the original poster, but I can't figure out how to do this in a more elementary way.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[e^{\pi i/n}]$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $R$ lying over the prime $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $v : R \to \mathbb{Q}$ be the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation, normalized so that $v(2)=1$. So equation \eqref{1} gives
$$v(\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}) + v(\beta+1+\beta^{-1}) = 1. \label{2}\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$

**Lemma** Let $\eta$ be a primitive $m$-th root of unity. Then
$$v(\eta+1+\eta^{-1}) = \begin{cases} \infty & m = 3 \\ 1/2^k & m = 3 \cdot 2^{k+1} \ \text{for} \ k \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

**Proof:** The case $\eta=1$ (so $m=1$) is easy to check by hand, so we assume that $\eta \neq 1$ from now on.

We have
$$\eta+1+\eta^{-1} = \eta^{-1} \frac{\eta^3-1}{\eta-1}$$
so
$$v(\eta+1+\eta^{-1}) = v(\eta^3-1) - v(\eta-1). \label{3}\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$
If $\omega$ is a primitive $\ell$-th root of unity, then
$$v(\omega-1) = \begin{cases} \infty & \ell=1 \\ 1/2^k & \ell = 2^{k+1} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}. \label{4} \tag{$\heartsuit$}$$
(See, for example, Chapter 8 in Washington's *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields.*)

Since $\eta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity, $\eta^3$ is a primitive $m/\text{GCD}(m,3)$-th root of unity, so combining \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} gives the claim. $\square$

Now, plug the Lemma into \eqref{2}. The only ways to write $1$ as a sum of numbers in $\{ \infty, 1, 1/2, 1/4, \cdots, 0 \}$ are $1+0$, $0+1$ and $1/2+1/2$.

If we are in the $1+0$ case, then $\alpha$ must be a primitive $6$-th root of unity, so $\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1} = 2$ and $\beta + 1 + \beta^{-1} = 1$, giving that $\beta$ is $\pm i$. Similarly, in the $0+1$ case, $\alpha$ is $\pm i$ and $\beta$ is a primitive $6$-th root of unity.

Finally, we are left with the $1/2+1/2$ case. In this case, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be primitive $12$-th roots of unity. This means that $\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}$, and $\beta+1+\beta^{-1}$ should be $1 \pm \sqrt{3}$. We get a near miss: $(1+\sqrt{3})(1-\sqrt{3})$ is $-2$, not $2$, so this solution to \eqref{2} doesn't yield a solution to \eqref{1}.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution (+1)! I will wait for two more days to see if there are any more solutions using more elementary methods, and then accept it.

Comment: There seems to be no need to open the brackets and close them again (in the beginning)

Comment: Just one question... when you wrote "In this case, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be primitive $12$-th roots of unity. This means that $\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}$, and $\beta+1+\beta^{-1}$ should be $1 \pm \sqrt{3}$.", how did you calculate $\alpha+1+\alpha^{-1}$? Is it just substituting the cosine values, or is there a neater trick?

Comment: I personally did it using the Mathematica command `MinimalPolynomial[E^(-2 Pi I/12) + 1+ E^(2 Pi I/12), x]` and then, when I saw that I got a quadratic, solving that quadratic. But a more reasonable method would be to remember that $\cos(\pm \pi/6) = \sqrt{3}/2$ and $\cos(\pm 5 \pi/6) = -\sqrt{3}/2$ :).

Comment: The equation obtained in the beginning claims that the sum of 9 roots of unity is 0. It is possible to (elementarily) describe all such 9-tuples, and then to check which of them are of the required form; that would be elementary, but I will not do that without a computer aid…

Comment: @Ilya, Conway & Jones did that in the paper I cite in my comment on OP's question.